# how to search for network in android studio while using socket?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, sockets, networking

```
    public void connect() {

        final String msg = "";
        Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                try {
                    s = new Socket("192.168.1.3", 1337);
                    textView.setText("Connection acquired");
                    out = s.getOutputStream();
                    output = new PrintWriter(out);
                    output.println(msg);
                    textView.setText("message sent : " + msg.length());
                    output.flush();

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        thread.start();
    }
```

I am using the above code to connect to desired IP [192.168.1.3]... I have created another program at the  other end... The problem is that the IP sometimes changes to 192.168.1.4 or 192.168.1.6... and when I use another network it changes to 192.168.43.2... now due to this I have to go every time into the code and change it manually.... 
                     Is there any function or any other thing that might search for IPs available then check if desired port exists and then connect... **Thanks in advance**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's why DNS names exist.  If you use an IP address, you have to use that exact address.  If you use DNS, you do a name->IP lookup.  Get a dynamic DNS provider and use that to give your server a name.

You really do not want to start port scanning to find open ports.  You will be treated as an attacker and kicked off the network, because you really would be doing something attackers do.